# Is a continuous function bounded on a set $\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let's consider  $$f:\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$$ a $C^1$  function such that, for every $y_0\in [a,b]$ we have that $f(x,y_0)\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, would that mean that $$\sup_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times [a,b]}|f(x,y)|$$ is bounded?

I believe it's true, but I don't know how to prove it, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is continuously differentiable in both variables $x$ and $y$?  And what is $H^1$?

Comment: Yes in both variables. $H^1(\mathbb{R}) is Sobolev space of order 1.

Comment: This is an outline and therefore needs verification, but suppose the contrary;  then there will be a sequence of points $(x_n, y_n) \in \mathbb R \times [a,b] $ for which $|f(x_n,y_n)| \to \infty $.  The points $y_n$ lie in a compact interval so a subsequence, $y_{n_k}$, will converge to a point $y_0$ in $[a,b]$.  The subsequence also has $|f(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})| \to \infty$.  Now consider $|f(x_{n_k}, y_0)|$.  I think that will be unbounded which contradicts its membership of $H^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I don't think that would work

Comment: You may be right - I have not been able to complete the last part of the argument.  It leads me to think that the proposition is false.

Comment: You mean simply $f(x,y)$ is bounded, right? Not $\sup|f(x,y)|$ is bounded.

Comment: I mean $|f(x,y)|$ is bounded

Comment: Then you should edit your post to remove the $\sup$. (Also, $|f(x,y)|$ is bounded if and only if $f(x,y)$ is bounded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (hopefully correct) counterexample:
Take any positive function $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\phi(x)=1$.

Let's define $f:\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{y}\phi(x-1/y)  \text{  for  }y\neq0 \\
0\text{  for  }y=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I claim that $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}\times[0,1])$. Clearly $f$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}\times (0,1]$ so we only need to consider points of the form $(x_0,0)$. From the compact support of $\phi$ it follows that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $(x_0,0)$ such that $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in U$ (Just take only small y's then the expression $\phi(x-1/y)$ will be zero) and therefore $f$ is smooth on $U$.

Clearly $f(\cdot,y)\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ for every $y\in [0,1]$ and
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}
\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]}f(x,y)=\infty
\end{align}